# Split current query to get distinct items

Tags: sql, t-sql

Sorry for the poor question title. Hopefully I can clarify here: I'm not sure if this is technically a CTE or if it just looks like one. Anyway, if you look at the output first, it will help to better describe what I'm looking for:

```
var_Year  var_Month   var_Day   Total_Downloads
2013      2           25        100
2013      2           24        200
2013      2           23        100
2013      2           22        200
2013      2           21        100
```

I want two additional columns to show the number of downloads by product instead of just the total. The desired output then would be the following:

```
var_Year  var_Month   var_Day   Total_Downloads   Downloads_Prod_A    Downloads_Prod_B
2013      2           25        100               50                  50
2013      2           24        200               90                  110
2013      2           23        100               25                  75
2013      2           22        200               125                 75
2013      2           21        100               90                  10
```

Here is the current SQL query, which is lacking the definition of "Product A" and "Product B". Assume that "f_product" is the field in the database that will contain either "Product A" or "Product B"

```
SELECT var_Year, var_Month, var_Day, COUNT(var_Day) AS "Total_Downloads"
 FROM
  ( SELECT 
    DISTINCT f_downloadIPaddress, 
    DATEPART(YEAR,f_downloadtimestamp) as var_Year, 
    DATEPART(MONTH,f_downloadtimestamp) as var_Month,
    DATEPART(DAY,f_downloadtimestamp) as var_Day
    FROM tb_downloads
  ) tb_tempcalendar
 GROUP BY var_Year, var_Month, var_Day
 ORDER BY var_Year desc, var_Month desc, var_Day DESC
```

I'm stumped, because I can't determine if I need another CTE inside of the current one, or if it can be done with a COUNT(DISTINCT x) method? Any assistance is appreciated. Using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks in advance,
Beems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand why you deleted your previous question, but anyway, the answer I posted there seems to still be valid for you, did you tried it?. Here is the answer:

What you have is a "derived table", not a CTE. Now, I think that you can jus query your table directly, like this:

```
SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR,f_downloadtimestamp) as var_Year, 
        DATEPART(MONTH,f_downloadtimestamp) as var_Month,
        DATEPART(DAY,f_downloadtimestamp) as var_Day,
        COUNT(DISTINCT f_downloadIPaddress) Total_Downloads,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN f_product = 'Product A' 
                           THEN f_downloadIPaddress END) Downloads_Prod_A,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN f_product = 'Product B' 
                           THEN f_downloadIPaddress END) Downloads_Prod_B
FROM tb_downloads
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,f_downloadtimestamp),
         DATEPART(MONTH,f_downloadtimestamp),
         DATEPART(DAY,f_downloadtimestamp)
ORDER BY var_Year desc, var_Month desc, var_Day DESC
```

Comment: Man, you stole the answer straight out from under me -- I was even going to talk about CTEs vs. derived tables :)

Comment: @ean5533 If this seems like a fast answer, its because I mostly copy-pasted a prevous answer to the same question, that the op deleted for some reason. No wizardry involved ;-)

Comment: I apologize. Thanks for the re-post of your answer. I work for a company that is hosting a product download for a software company, and they requested some reporting features that we didn't have so I was building a custom table for them. Unfortunately, I inadvertently posted some identifying information in the original post. I would have simply edited the original, but your code already had the information in it.

Comment: Thanks, this is working. One thing I'm not understanding yet is why the original in my question and your answer give different totals for "Total_Downloads". I'm trying to wrap my head around why. If I run them side-by-side, they don't match. For days where "Product A" and "Product B" equal zero "Total_Downloads" matches, but on days where there are numbers, our "Total_Downloads" fields don't match.

Comment: @Beems The solution on your original query was using `SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` for the calculation for product A and product B, meaning that it will count as a download for every record, and not for every distinct ip address. This is different to this answer, where I'm counting different ip addresses for the downloads of the products, meaning that if you have the same ip address on your table with the same product, it will only count as one download.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this with `count (distinct)`:

```
SELECT var_Year, var_Month, var_Day, COUNT(distinct f_downloadIPaddress) AS "Total_Downloads",
       count(distinct case when d.product = 'A' then f_downloadIPaddress end) as ProductA,
       count(distinct case when d.product = 'B' then f_downloadIPaddress end) as ProductB
FROM (SELECT d.*, 
             DATEPART(YEAR,f_downloadtimestamp) as var_Year, 
             DATEPART(MONTH,f_downloadtimestamp) as var_Month,
             DATEPART(DAY,f_downloadtimestamp) as var_Day,
      FROM tb_downloads d
     ) d
 GROUP BY var_Year, var_Month, var_Day
 ORDER BY var_Year desc, var_Month desc, var_Day DESC
```

Do note:  the sum of the two columns may be larger than the total.  This occurs when the same IP address has both products.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! I was unaware that the "CASE" syntax existed, so you have likely helped me in more significant ways than just this. Thanks again, Beems